# How to detect if select dropdown is in expanded state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where there are 3 dropdowns and 1 search button. As per project requirement , when we click enter on any of the 3 dropdowns, search button should be clicked automatically.

```
function searchOnEvent(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        searchClient(); // click search button.
    }   
}
```

On select element we put key up and down  event like this.

```
onKeyDown="searchOnEvent" onKeyUp="searchOnEvent"
```

Now issue is that when i select value from dropdown using down arrow key and then click Enter to select its value , search event also fired at the same time.,but this is not the expected behavior.
So i don't want to fire search event in case dropdown is in expanded state.

Any ideas?

Comment: add an `onchange` function in your select element like `onchange="searchClient();"`

Comment: I want to call searchEvent on click of Enter on dropdown so can't call onchange event.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an onchange event on your select box if you want to run function which is on your search button

```
<select id="your_select1_id" onchange="searchClient();">

   // select options

</select>

<input type="button" value="Search" id="search" onclick="searchClient();" />
```